# Debugging 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: substrate-node-template

Somehow our node starts to yield `429` errors and we do not find a reason for this. More specifically, we do not even know hot to debug this.

I see that [this gentlemen](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/7039) has logging for accepted connections, I do not see that, even with loglevel debug.

What is the number of `Too many requests` in substrate and how do I configure and monitor it?

Answer (score 0):

> You are doing the call against the old HTTP server right i.e, port
> --rpc-port, correct? **It will use the default value by jsonrpsee which causes that to be 100** which was a breaking change I realized now.

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13561#issuecomment-1462243398

The link you referenced has lots of good explanations. As noted [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/7039#issuecomment-1503160752) consider switching to the WS server which supports both HTTP and WebSocket. If you switch to WS using `--ws-port` then it will use `--ws-max-connections`.

This issue will be permnanently fixed here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13384

Comment: Switch to `--ws-port` from what? I currently have `--ws-external`, but this needs to stay on top of `--ws-port` right?

Comment: Can you update your post with the flags that you are currently using?